# how to query sails-disk in sailsjs

Tags: database, sails.js

I have generated the api in sailsjs using
sails generate api testAPI

and I have been able to create data using the command

```
http://localhost:1337/testAPI/create?username=f1&password=123
```

and i can get the result
but when I want to customize the route
for get - `http://localhost:1337/testAPI/1`
i am using the code

```
module.exports = {
    findOne:function(req,res){

        res.ok('overridden');
    }
};
```

in testAPIController.js for the overriding
and when I go the route `http://localhost:1337/testAPI/1` I am able to see overriden displayed there.
but how do I query the data and show a customized view there?

to customize and query the data I am using this code and it doesnt work
says that testAPI not defined

```
module.exports = {
    findOne:function(req,res){
      var results =  testAPI.find()
        res.ok(results);

    }
};
```

so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Refer the sails documentation. You have to use res.view to render the view. And Model.find({ search critieria }).exec( function(err,results ){ 
res.send(result);
})

Comment: This has a lot of examples : https://github.com/sailsinaction

Answer (score 1):

The model you created should be used with the first capital letter (**T**estAPI.find());

Also, you should consider the assync factor when fetching data. See code bellow

```
module.exports = {
    findOne:function(req,res){
      TestAPI.find().then(function(results) {
        return res.ok(results);
       });
    }
};
```